# Is it possible to repack MSI-package on UNIX?

Tags: windows-installer

Is it possible to repack MSI-package on UNIX?

We would like to allow our users to download MSI package from our web-application that is working on AIX system.
And there is idea to modify MSI package during deployment of web application or during downloading of MSI package - unpack MSI package, change config file and pack package again.

Is it possible to do on AIX(UNIX)?
Is it possible to do on other systems?

Comment: What do you use to create MSI package?

Comment: @Igor Shenderchuk Do not know yet. I've never worked with MSI before. I think we will use some free tool. Nullsoft NSIS Installer, Advanced Installer or Inno Setup.

Comment: NSIS Installer and Inno Setup don't create MSI installations. AdvancedInstaller is not bad, but free version is a bit restricted. I could suggest look into WiX - it's free and powerful. But any of this will not work on AIX, as I know.

Comment: @Igor Shenderchuk I am going to create installation package on Windows. On AIX I was requested to provide ability to change and repack package. But I think it is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that is possible, because at least you need authoring tools (Orca, Insted, InstallShield, etc) to edit MSI-package, which exist only in Windows environment. 
So, the simpliest way will be copy MSI-package to Windows platform and do required changes.

**Update 1**
If you need change a several options in config file, the better will be use *IniFile* table (if config has ini structure) or some Custom Action which will change config file during installation. Set proper conditions based on some Public Property to launch either Custom Action or changes in *IniFile* table. And then during downloading you will need only change MSI file (not files, which are inside), so in my opinion is easier and more rational.
How change Windows Installer MSI-Package on Unix platform? It is question?  I heard about [msitools](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools) project which should allow editing MSI files on linux, but don't sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The WineAPI as [implemented](http://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/msi.html) a bit of the MSI API.  That would be where to start if this is possible at all. I know how to do this on Windows but have never tried on other platforms.